# In a networked distributed quantum computing environment, How qubits will be transmitted/represented on the wire?

Tags: quantum-information

Posting this question here because it is about Quantum States/Qubit.

Currently quantum computers are based on a scale up architecture where you have these massive sites/machines.

I imagine a world where quantum computers become the size of our home desktop (Perhaps not mobile size... yet)

I imagine a world of distributed quantum systems (today's equivalent of distributed systems) where these quantum systems will be connected together via some Internet Protocol Stack that is built ground up for Quantum Computers. A scale out architecture, that is.

In view of the above, here's my question:

Today's fiber optic cables modulate the light to represent the binary data (1/0) it receives from the source. In a networked distributed quantum computing environment, how will qubits be transmitted/represented on the wire?

Comment: The standard approach is to use individual photons to encode quantum information, and send these photons through optical fibers between nodes. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes Chris! You are so kind to explain to me. What is the difference between this photons and the current fiber optic cables?

Comment: @NathanAw your question is ill-posed. You can transmit single photons (that is, *quantum* information) in the same fiber optic cables that are used for classical communication. What changes is the kind of devices that are needed to transmit/receive such information.